# How can I acces data from a soql inner query in a lightning web component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

How can I access data from an inner query in lwc? Here's my code:

JS:

```
@wire(getProducts)
wiredProducts({error, data}){
    if(error){
        this.error = error;
    }else if(data){
        console.log(data);
        this.products = data;
        this.listprice = this.products.Product_Price_Entries__r.List_Price__c;
        console.log('ex'+listprice);
    }
}
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
public with sharing class ProductCatalogController  {
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static List<Product__c> getProductsList(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Store_Short_Description__c, Image__c, (SELECT List_Price__c FROM Product_Price_Entries__r)
            FROM Product__c
            WHERE Name != null
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
             Limit 10];
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template for:each={products} for:item="product">
    <div key={product.Id} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
        <lightning-card class="cardBorder">
                    
            <div class="slds-m-bottom_medium">
                <lightning-formatted-number
                        value={products.listprice}
                        format-style="currency"> </lightning-formatted-number>
            </div> 
                  
        </lightning-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm trying to access the ListPrice value, how can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

The `Product_Price_Entries__r` should translate as an array, so you should be able to loop through and access each child record item individually. You should get the value of the first product price entry like this:

```
this.listprice = this.products.Product_Price_Entries__r[0].List_Price__c;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing the subquery and want to access the value in Your Lightning Web Component, You can access the values at both HTML file and JS.

In Html,

You can do like below. In this example, i have taken account and contacts. You can access all the contact of an account queried as sub-query using relationship name:-

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="ApexWireMethodToFunction" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={accounts}>
                <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
                    <p key={account.Id}>{account.Name}</p>
                    <template for:each={account.Contacts} for:item="contact">
                        <p key={contact.Id}>{contact.Id}</p>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

If you want to access the child value in jS directly, You can use a loop to access the value. You cannot directly access the value in the way you were trying in your question.

```
@wire(getAccountList)
wiredProducts({error, data}){
    if(error){
        this.error = error;
    }else if(data){
        this.accounts = data;
        this.accounts.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.Contacts);
        });
    }
}
```